# I can't find the file on my phone while using new File() function

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a voice changer but when i can't find the file.
this is my code.
this code is after recording the voice and adding the effect.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

        int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;

        int bufferSizeInBytes = (int)(file.length()/shortSizeInBytes);
        short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

            int i = 0;
            while(dataInputStream.available() > 0){
                audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                i++;
            }

            dataInputStream.close();

            int Freq = Integer.parseInt( txtFreq.getText().toString());

            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                    3,
                    Freq,
                    2,
                    2,
                    bufferSizeInBytes,
                    1);

            audioTrack.play();
            audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

so what is the directory where i can find the file?

Comment: Are you trying to write a file to external storage? This code is for reading a file "test.pcm" from external storage and playing back it's content. You're not writing anything.

Comment: i'm trying to save the file after adding the effects but i can't find the code to write this again

Comment: Statement `new File()` does not create a file on storage. So you will find nothing on storage.

Comment: is there anyway to save it using another function

Comment: You are only trying to read a file using FileInputSTream(). So what do you think you should use when you write a file? FileOutputStream().

Comment: I don't know how to use it

Comment: https://github.com/aahlenst/android-audiorecord-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/audiorecord/AudioRecordActivity.java
use this example. it records audio end then writes the file to external storage. What you need is line 143-161 in class RecordingRunnable.